# Hide Image when another image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

this seems to be simple.. but I am a bit noobish with jquery, maybe I am doing something silly wrong?

I want to click an image, and on that click, hide another image right next to it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

 
        $("#butShowMeSomeUnits").click(function() { 
            $('#arrowUnitspic').hide();
        });
 
      
 </script>
```

Id's are correct as per the two images. What am I missing? Debugging it, the code never gets fired...

Thanks

EDIT

I had my control as a nested control on an asp masterpage, and its id was being rewritten. I have now fixed the id, but I still cant get any joy... I also see my markup is being rendered as an "input", would that make a difference?

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#butShowMeSomeUnits").click(function () {
                $('#arrowUnitspic').hide();
            });
        });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="image" src="bookings_media/buttons/show-me-some-units.png" onmouseout="this.src='bookings_media/buttons/show-me-some-units.png'" onmouseover="this.src='bookings_media/buttons/show-me-some-units_orange.png'" id="butShowMeSomeUnits" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$bookings_right_content$butShowMeSomeUnits">
</body>
```

EDIT
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JwAYb/)

If there is any confusion... the JS fiddle I spooled up with the exact code also does not work...

Comment: Is that code *before* the `<img>` elements?  If so, put it *after* them.

Comment: Can you provide HTML or fiddle?

Comment: For future reference, its nice to include a link to a jsFiddle for debugging purposes.

Comment: Yeah, I have this in the head basically. Are you implying that the code does not yet "know" about the elements, and therefore does not bind to them?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder, yes. You have to have `$(document).ready(function() {`...code... `});` around your code so it loads after all other html/css code.

Comment: I edited the question and added new info

Comment: Where is the arrowUnitspic in your html sample?

Comment: Right next to butShowMeSomeUnits, preceding it. (both of those, quite far down the doc.

Comment: I'm not referring to the script element, Can you also include the html tag for the arrowUnitspic html element? I will assume there are other html elements on the page, but it might be useful to see it.

Comment: I added a fiddle with the relevant code as rendered in my document... ... in the fiddle

Comment: Sorry, edited the fiddle link. I tried to update the old one, have added a new one now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do do on page ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#butShowMeSomeUnits").click(function() { 
            $('#arrowUnitspic').hide();
        });
});
</script>
```

Edit:
The fiddle you provided did not work until I chose jQuery 1.10.1 from the dropdown. You will notice your onmouseover changes the element first, but once you click on the input it does hide the image. Can you verify this works the same for you?

If the answer is no then I don't think you are loading the jQuery library on your page. To check this should work:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

    alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
```

In addition it might be helpful to see what errors your browser console /dev tools is showing.

Comment: Not necessary if the script is at the bottom of the page

Comment: First, it doesn't matter if the codes on the bottom of the page, but even if that is true, proper form is to have it somewhere in the head tag. Also your comment is not based in any facts from what is in the question. You cannot assume his code is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I don't think so .. Your should avoid placing the script in the head unless and absolutely necessary.. It will make your pages load slower because the DOM rendering is stopped due to parsing of the scripts.. Check this http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: At my place of employment we serve from multiple domains / CDN so its a non issue. Also for jquery google hosts it now-a-days.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder This thread got cold. Were you able to solve your issue or do you need more help?

Comment: @Shawn Nope, was not able to solve this. Moved on for the moment to return to try and get it working later.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in jQuery.ready() event. And also check whether jquery js file is loaded or not.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#butShowMeSomeUnits").click(function() { 
                $('#arrowUnitspic').hide();
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks good and works check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/D4wkW/)**

What you might be missisng is either:

- to load jQuery script in the head of your page.
- to include `$(document).ready(function() { //code here });` in case your `<img>` tags are after the script in the page code. This is so your code loads when page is ready/loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that may help you:

1. make sure you integrate jQuery lib right. (to check that you might wanna open console on chrome and type `$("html").hide();` and see if the current page dissapears)
2. make sure your custom JS file or code is UNDER the including of jQuery lib.
3. very good starting point with jQuery is to put everything in `$(document).ready()` as below example:

   $(document).ready(function(){
               $("img").click(function(){
               $("img").hide();
               $(this).show();
               });
           });