# Keeping an ASP button from doing a Postback

Tags: asp.net, postback

I've run into a strange problem with a ASP.NET project. Upon clicking a button, I execute a JavaScript function that adds an image to an img control. However, clicking the button refreshes the page, causing the image to disappear.

I've tried setting the UseSubmitBehavior to false, I recall this fixing a similar problem I've had before. Strangely enough, that doesn't seem to work.

When I inspect the page, I can see that the button's type has changed from "submit" to "button" but the OnClick event suddenly has gained a method "_doPostback", leaving me with the exact same problem.

How can I make sure that the _doPostback doesn't get added to my OnClick event? Or is there another way to prevent my button from doing a postback?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have just answered one of my own questions.. with your question. Thanks indeed... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706846/hide-image-when-another-image-is-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="myJavaScriptfunction(); return false;" />
```

the `return false` statement prevents any postbacks.

You can also use an anchor tag with the `href` set to `#`.